# Is this operator T compact on $L^2([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Consider $L^2([0,1])$ and the operator $$Tu(t) = tu(t)$$for a.e. $t \in [0,1]$

How can I prove or disprove that T is compact?
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm What is $x(t)$?

Comment: @AsemAbdelraouf sorry it was an error. I fixed the text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  $T$ is self-adjoint and has no eigenvectors. Use the spectral theorem.

Comment: Simply elegant!! Many thanks

Comment: You don't even need self-adjoint. For example here $1\in \sigma(T)$ but $1$ is not an eigenvalue. This would work in $L^p$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $f_n(x)=n^{3/2}\boldsymbol 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Set $K=\{f_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\subset L^2(0,1)$. Is $K$ bounded ? Is $T(K)$ relatively compact ?

Answer (score 0):

On the infinite dimensional invariant subspace $\{f\in L_2([0,1]): f_{[0,1/2]}=0\}$ the operator is invertible.